# Fix HTML structure

Tags: html, structure

I know this is a strange question, but maybe some of you have had the same problem. I run a website where user share notes, papers and any other kind of documents, written in HTML. The problem is that the content structure is not very good: usually, they don't use headings (h2,h3,etc.), <ul> and <ol> lists (they write lists as plain text), and so on.

Has anyone experienced this kind of problems? How can I address this problem? I've tried with some heavy regex-based solutions, but they are not very accurate.

---

### Example

> **Demand-** quantities of a good or service that
>   people are ready to buy at various prices within some given time peiod
>   other factors besides price held constant.
>
> FACTORS THAT CAN CAUSE DEMAND TO
>   CHANGE:
>
> 1. Taste and Preferences
>
> 2. Income
>
> NON-PRICE DETERMINANTS OF
>   SUPPLY:
>
> 1. Costs and Technology
>
> 2. Price of other
>   Goods and Services Offered

Must be converted to:

> ### Demand
>
> Quantities of a good or service that
>   people are ready to buy at various prices within some given time peiod
>   other factors besides price held constant.
>
> #### FACTORS THAT CAN CAUSE DEMAND TO
>   CHANGE
>
> 1. Taste and Preferences
> 2. Income
>
> #### NON-PRICE DETERMINANTS OF SUPPLY
>
> 1. Costs and Technology
> 2. Price of other
>      Goods and Services Offered

Comment: By looking at the example input, I'd try [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). Forget RegEx for this, it will be hell.

Comment: but the source is HTML, I have to work in HTML level, markdown is not a solution

Comment: There are multiple MD > HTML converters, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you disable any existing HTML capabilities from your editor, and use a simple textarea instead, where the users would enter the content with markdown formatting (which is very close to what they're currently doing).

There are many converters from Markdown to HTML, for several languages (see for example this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Markdown_implementations)). So you can use a JavaScript implementation for a live preview (like Stack Overflow does), and use another server-side parser to convert the content when creating your HTML views from the database.

Comment: Markdown would be a very clean solution, but I can't change the writing habit of my users. Also, they have a good WYSIWYG editor which support of heading and lists but they don't use it :(